# why classes.dex file changed after I repacked the apk?

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering, apktool

I repacked the apk file with apktool, but I didn't change anything.
I know that repacking the apk will cause the signature changed, but I don't understand why classes.dex file will change?(Because the sha-1 value of classes.dex in META-INF/Manifest.MF has changed, but I didn't change the code.)

Does 'apktool d XXX.apk' will change the code? Where does it change?
Can somebody explain the reason to me ?

Comment: `apktool` recompiles smali to dex, and may not generate exactly the original dex code.

Answer (score 0):

When you unpack `classes.dex` using `apktool` it get's decompiled to `smali` files.

Next when you recompile it back, even if you have not changed anything, the `apktool` compiler, compiles it back from `smali` to `dex`.

Hence the signature of the file changes. And that is the same reason you should also resign the app once again.